# Fetching date/time from string in R

Tags: regex, r, datetime

I have a string lets say like this

> Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock

And, I wish to fetch the date from it as

> May 13, 2013

Is there any way I can do this in R? I have tried strptime function in the following way:

```
strptime("Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock", " %b %d, %Y")
```

I get **`"NA"`**

But when I try it without any words before the date like

```
strptime("May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock", " %b %d, %Y")
```

I get output as **`"2013-05-13"`**

I have also tried regex like

```
grep("Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock", "?(?:[a-zA-Z]*)(\\s+)(?:[0-9]*)(,)(\\s+)(?:[0-9]*)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for showing what you had tried. Assuming all the datetimes have the same format, you can use this:

```
s <- "Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock"
month.abb.pattern <- paste(month.abb,collapse="|")
datetime.fmt <- "%b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p"
strptime(substr(s, regexpr(month.abb.pattern, s), nchar(s)), datetime.fmt)
```

Answer (score 5):

This uses `strapply` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com).  It matches the regular expression `pat` to each string passing the substrings that match the parenthesized portions of the regular expression as separate arguments to `to.POSIXct` and then finally assembling that function's output.  We have assumed the same date and time format exists in each instance but have not assumed much about the surrounding text:

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- c("Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock", 
            "The date is Jun 6, 2013 and the time is 11:18 pm")

pat <- "(\\w+ \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}).*(\\d{2}:\\d{2} [ap]m)"
to.POSIXct <- function(d, t) as.POSIXct(paste(d, t), format = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
strapply(s, pat, to.POSIXct, simplify = "c")
```

which gives

```
[1] "2013-05-13 10:55:00 EDT" "2013-06-06 23:18:00 EDT"
```

UPDATE: correction

Answer (score 1):

With your second attempt you're on the right path. Just get rid of everything prior to the date using `strsplit` with the `split` argument being `says:`:

```
strptime(strsplit("Ankit says: May 13, 2013 at 10:55 am you rock","says: ")[[1]][2],
         format= "%b %d, %Y")
[1] "2013-05-13"
```

If you want to automatize that to many log entries:

```
strptime(do.call(rbind,strsplit(your_log_as_a_vector, "says: "))[,2],
         format = "%b %d, %Y")
```

**Edit**: Indeed there is the issue that the string can contains `says:` later. Then the following would work (since even though there is a second `says` it will always appear after the date, so the chunk containing the date will always be the second one):

```
 strptime(sapply(strsplit(your_log_as_a_vector, "says: "),`[`,2),
         format = "%b %d, %Y")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not an option as this is not the entire string and the string may contain another "says:"...

Comment: ok fair enough. See edit. I leave this one for the sake of completeness but the two other solution are far better.